# splice(index,1) not removing element

Tags: html, vuejs2

I am writing a small program in Vue.js, but I am getting stuck with an error.

I want the `X` button to remove each item in a list. I used `splice(index,1)`, but the item isn't being removed. What am I missing?

**My HTML:**

```
<div id="app" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h1>Add Student</h1>  
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" v-model="newStudent.name" class = "form-control" placeholder="Student Name">
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="address">Address</label>
          <input type="text" id="address" v-model="newStudent.address" class = "form-control" placeholder="Address">
        </div>  
        <button class="btn btn-success" v-on:click = "addStudent">Add</button>  
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1>All Students</h1>
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>Address</td>
              <td>Action</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for = "student in students">
              <td>{{student.name}}</td>
              <td>{{student.address}}</td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="deleteStudent($index)">X</button></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div> <!--End of Row-->
    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <pre>{{ $data |  json }}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**My JS:**

```
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      newStudent: {name: "", address: ""},
      students: []
    },
    methods: {
      addStudent: function(){
        var name = this.newStudent.name.trim();
        var address = this.newStudent.address.trim();
        if(name && address){
          this.students.push({name: name, address: address});
          this.newStudent = {name: "", address: ""};
          $("#name").focus();
        }
      },
      deleteStudent: function(index){
        this.students.splice(index,1)
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$index` variable [was removed in Vue 2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#index-and-key-removed). So, you're not passing the index in correctly.

Specify the `index` variable in the `v-for` and pass that to the `deleteStudent` method instead:

```
<tr v-for="student, index in students">
  <td>{{student.name}}</td>
  <td>{{student.address}}</td>
  <td>
    <button 
      type="button" 
      class="btn btn-danger" 
      v-on:click="deleteStudent(index)"
    >X</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

[This is covered in the documentation on list rendering in Vue.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html)

Comment: Thank you. It works. The tutorial might be the old one.